# How variables are catched inside anonymous method?

Tags: delphi

Is this code valid:

```
  TMyObj = class(Tobject)
  public
    FThread: TThread;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyObj.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FThread:= TThread.createAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while not FThread.CheckTerminated do sleep(10000); 
    end);
  FThread.start;
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

my question is after i do

```
destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

I mean after the object TMyObj is free, what will be the value of `FThread` inside

```
  FThread:= TThread.createAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while not FThread.CheckTerminated do sleep(10000); 
    end);
```

Comment: Variable capture is for local variables. In this case the variable that is captured is `Self`, and `FThread` is not captured directly. If you subsequently destroy that object then it, and all of its fields, are no longer valid.

Comment: Not a duplicate imo because the referenced question and answers are not addressing the fact of capturing fields of objects causing the containing object to be captured instead.

Comment: It would be better to describe exactly what you want to achieve, especially since this example does absolutely nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this code is not valid.

It is important to know that `FThread` is not captured, but the reference to the containing instance. So the anonymous method code rather looks like this:

```
FThread := TThread.createAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    while not Self.FThread.CheckTerminated do sleep(10000); 
  end);
```

The compiler generates an object that implements the anonymous method with a field called `Self` that captures the reference to the `TMyObj` instance. If that instance gets destroyed while the anonymous method is alive within the thread, it will have a dangling reference.

A thread created with `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` is destroyed automatically when it finishes. So if you store that in a field for later access, you at least need to turn `FreeOnTerminate` off and not reference it via a captured variable to the thread itself, but rather with `TThread.Current`. Within the anonymous method, this will give you the thread that method is running in.

Comment: Thanks! So how can I update this code to make it valid ?

Comment: 1. Add an `OnTerminate` event handler (before you call `Start`). 2. In that `OnTerminate` event handler set `FThread` to `nil`. 3. Call `FThread.Free` in the destructor of your class.  4. Realise that an anonymous, free on terminate thread is not in fact the right choice and change the design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You would also have to detach the `OnTerminate` event handler in the destructor or it might run after the containing class was destroyed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I realize that an anonymous, free on terminate thread is not in fact the right choice and change the design